# How To Bind Two different Items

Tags: c#, xamarin

how can two different items in a list  be bound to one another hence when one is deleted its bound patner is also deleted.The question may sound simple, but the items are in two different lists.

```
 public class MyClass{

 public StackLayout SavedHoursLayout = new StackLayout {};
 public Label RemoveHoursLabel;
 public TapGestureRecognizer RemoveTapped;
 public Grid HoursRemoveGrid;
 public Button AddHoursButton = new Button();
 public Label Correct = new Label{Text="Correct"};
 public list<Label> ItemsLayout = new list<Label>();

 public MyClass()
 {
      Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = { AddHoursButton,SavedHoursLayout }
        }
        AddHoursButton.Clicked+=AddHoursButton_Clicked;

 }
    public void AddSavedHours()
     {
      Label Time = new Label { };
      RemoveHoursLabel = new Label { 
     Text="remove",TextColor=Color.Red,FontAttributes=FontAttributes.Italic};
      HoursRemoveGrid = new Grid();
      RemoveTapped = new TapGestureRecognizer();
      this.BindingContext = HoursRemoveGrid;

      HoursRemoveGrid.Children.Add(Time,0,0);
      HoursRemoveGrid.Children.Add(RemoveHoursLabel,1,0);
      SavedHoursLayout.Children.Add(HoursRemoveGrid);

      RemoveHoursLabel.GestureRecognizers.Add(RemoveTapped);
      RemoveTapped.Tapped += RemoveTapped_Tapped;
      ItemsLayout.Children.Add(Correct);

      void RemoveTapped_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
       var grid = (sender as Label).Parent as Grid;
       int position = SavedHoursLayout.Children.IndexOf(grid);
        SavedHoursLayout.Children.RemoveAt(position);
      }
     }

       private void AddHoursButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
     {
        AddSavedHours();
     }
 }
```

**Question**
Now when i click `RemoveHourLabel`, i want to remove the `Label Correct`in `ItemsLayout`corresponding to the `RemovehoursGrid`.

**NB**
There are already a number of Labels in `ItemsLayout`,  so each `Label Correct` does not have the same index as that of its correspondent `RemoveHoursGrid`.

Comment: the code messes up ui and data logic. hardly maitainable. try use [mvvm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel)?

Comment: @LeiYang,Thanks but how does this help in anyway.

Comment: i think of mvvm when you say 'binding' in the title. however i didn't see anything bound. instead all the winforms style.

Comment: @LeiYang,I Changed the `string Correct` to  `Label Correct`.

Comment: "this.BindingContext = HoursRemoveGrid;" - this is very, very wrong

Comment: @Jason, but it hasn't given me any error ,but can you explain.

Comment: honestly, your code just doesn't make any sense.  You mention ListView in your question but I don't see that used anywhere in your code.  And I don't see any actual Binding either.  Just setting the BindingContext by itself doesn't do anything.  And your assigning of a Grid as the BindingContext implies (sorry to be blunt) that you have no idea how Binding works.

Comment: @Jason,its list not listview i made a mistake i have corrected it. Can you please write down how you understand my question so i will know what you are looking at here and correct some things

Comment: Did you solved your problem or tried my solution?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT, yes i tried it ,  it did not work, it did not remove it .

Comment: Did you get the tempLabel from tempItemsLayout when you remove hour label? I tested and it removed on my side.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can create a new `list<Label>` to hold the labels so that it will have the  same index as that of its correspondent `RemoveHoursGrid`.

First, create a new list, let's call it `tempItemsLayout` :

```
public List<Label> tempItemsLayout = new List<Label>();
```

Then in your method `AddSavedHours`, Add the correct to tempItemsLayout too:

```
public void AddSavedHours()
{    
    //...other codes

    RemoveHoursLabel.GestureRecognizers.Add(RemoveTapped);
    RemoveTapped.Tapped += RemoveTapped_Tapped;
    ItemsLayout.Add(Correct);

    //Add the correct to tempItemsLayout too
    tempItemsLayout.Add(Correct);

    //...other codes
}
```

Then in your `RemoveTapped_Tapped`, Remove the label from both tempItemsLayout and ItemsLayout:

```
void RemoveTapped_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = (sender as Label).Parent as Grid;
        int position = SavedHoursLayout.Children.IndexOf(grid);
        SavedHoursLayout.Children.RemoveAt(position);

        Label tempLabel = tempItemsLayout[position];

        //Remove the label from both tempItemsLayout and ItemsLayout
        tempItemsLayout.Remove(tempLabel);

        ItemsLayout.Remove(tempLabel);
}
```

Try and let me know if it works.

Comment: I get an error at ` Label tempLabel = tempItemsLayout[position];` say the index is out of range. but this is not the first time i am getting this error, it always happens when i try to use `int position `  more than once (that is, i have already used it in `SavedHoursLayout.Children.RemoveAt(position);`).

Comment: @lois I can't reproduce the error on my side. Is there any other code in your project beside the codes in your question? Are you using `SavedHoursLayout` in anywhere else?  You can post all your code so that I can test for you.